# Configure App A (Non-SSO) to authenticate and redirect with App B (SAML SSO)

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I have an application (App A) that does not implement SSO. It uses its own datastore to authenticate users. What we've been tasked to do is when a user clicks on a button within our application (App A) it needs to redirect the user to another third-party application (App B), authenticate via SAML, and pass data in that payload.

How would I implement this without changing my apps current authentication process? I can't seem to find any resources on using SAML to connect to third-party applications from non-sso applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use SAML, you need one side to be the SP (App B) and the other side to be a SAML IDP (App B).

So you need to have SAML on the [RP](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43) and on the IDP (App B) where you need to authenticate.

This is because SAML is an SSO protocol that needs both sides to conform.

So the button you add needs to use a client-side SAML stack to kick off the process.